# module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'yaxis'

Tags: python

I know this isn't reproducable but I'm not sure enough what is happening to make it that way.  I'll update and re-answer if someone can explain.

```
ax = plt.plot( 'spending_billions', 'poverty_rates', data=pv_rates_df, marker='o', color='blue', linewidth=2, label = 'Black Poverty Rate')
plt.title("Black Poverty and Cash Reparations", fontsize=12, fontweight=0, color='Black')
plt.xlabel("Spending in Billions")
plt.ylabel("SPM Black Poverty Rates")
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 22, 2))
plt.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
plt.legend()
```

I get this error.  module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'yaxis'

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks.  That doesn't seem to work.  Anyone else have any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry. 'list' object has no attribute 'yaxis'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error message says, `yaxis` does not exist on your `plt` object.

If you use `pandas.DataFrame.plot`, the return value is in fact `matplotlib.axes.Axes`, as your variable naming suggests. It seems however that you're using `matplotlib.pyplot.plot`, which returns a list of `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` objects.

`yaxis` is an attribute of `matplotlib.axes.Axes`. To get your current `matplotlib.axes.Axes` instance, you can use `matplotlib.gca()` (get current axes). So the following works:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

plt.scatter(range(5), range(5), s=3)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.PercentFormatter())
plt.show()
```